# signing a certifcate using osslsigncode will affect HTTPS?

Tags: https, openssl, digital-certificate

i have a pfx file with password i can re sign the certficate using OSSLSIGNCODE whether it will effect HTTPS(ex"https://domain.com).
is this osslsigncode will create self signed certificate?.if it is a self signed certificate means it will effect my https right.kindly give suggestion to me regard this.

Comment: please can anyone give suggestions on this.

Comment: `osslsigncode` is a tool to sign binary (windows) code with a given certificate. It is not meant to sign new certificates. If you want to do that, you have to use `openssl`, or an equivalent software.